# Twilio Client Call Out Implementation

Tags: twilio

I am developing a mobile app with the Twilio Client and I have an implementation question.  My app needs to dial a number and when the call is answered play a message.  Using Twiml  verb can I play a message with  to the person that answers the call?  Or is this something I need to create a conference to accomplish?

I have tried to use the action url of the Dial to respond with Twiml when the call is answered but it doesn't seem to work.  I sometimes get the callback when the call has ended but even that is sporadic.

Here is the php code for calling out:

```
<?php
include('../Twilio/autoload.php');
include('./config.php');

use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml;

if (isset($_REQUEST['To']) && strlen($_REQUEST['To']) > 0) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['To']);
    $dial = $response->dial(array('callerId' => $TWILIO_CALLER_ID, 
        'action' => 'http://www.example.com/ios/status.php'));

    if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
        $dial->number($number);
    } else {
        $dial->client($number);
    }
} else {
    $response->say("Thanks for calling!");
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request) example from Twilio? Looks like you need to initiate the call, set an on answered response where you define a `<Say>` or `<Play>`. See step 6 from the link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Thev, thanks for offering some support to the Twilio community here. Can we send you a t-shirt? Email mspeir@twilio.com for details.